# R: How to drop the corresponding rows if there is a 1 in columns with a column name containing a specific string

Tags: r, dplyr, drop

I would like to drop a whole row if there is a 1 in any column having a name that ends with "rem" or "nocut".
Sorry, I can't list the whole data set here because it's too large.
Here is an example of my data:

```
Sequence| #1C_cut  | #2C_nocut | #1C_rem | #3C_cut | #3C_rem | #4C_nocut|
R1      |    0     |     0     |    1    |    1    |    0    |     0    |
R2      |    0     |     1     |    0    |    0    |    0    |     1    |
R3      |    1     |     0     |    0    |    0    |    0    |     0    |
R4      |    0     |     0     |    0    |    1    |    0    |     0    |
R5      |    1     |     0     |    0    |    1    |    0    |     0    |
```

What I want:

```
Sequence| #1C_cut  | #2C_nocut | #1C_rem | #3C_cut | #3C_rem | #4C_nocut|
R3      |    1     |     0     |    0    |    0    |    0    |     0    |
R4      |    0     |     0     |    0    |    1    |    0    |     0    |
R5      |    1     |     0     |    0    |    1    |    0    |     0    |
```

I have an idea of combining select() and filter() function in dplyr to solve this problem, but I don't know how to do that......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing the idea from @jrcalabrese. Without manipulating the data (`mutate()`), you can `filter()` as such:

```
df %>%  
  filter(if_all(ends_with(c("_rem", "_nocut")), ~ .x != 1))

# A tibble: 3 × 7
  Sequence `1C_cut` `2C_nocut` `1C_rem` `3C_cut` `3C_rem` `4C_nocut`
  <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
1 R3              1          0        0        0        0          0
2 R4              0          0        0        1        0          0
3 R5              1          0        0        1        0          0
```

Answer (score 1):

One `tidyverse` solution would be to find all the 1s contained in variables that end with `_rem` or `_nocut` (using `across(ends_with))`), replace those 1s with `NA` using `ifelse`, and then use `drop_na` to remove those rows entirely.

This code works for the dataset you included, but one major limitation of this code is that it assumes that there are no other `NA` values in your dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_delim("
Sequence|1C_cut|2C_nocut|1C_rem|3C_cut|3C_rem|4C_nocut
R1|0|0|1|1|0|0
R2|0|1|0|0|0|1
R3|1|0|0|0|0|0
R4|0|0|0|1|0|0
R5|1|0|0|1|0|0
")

df %>%
  mutate(across( ( ends_with("_rem") | ends_with("_nocut") ), ~ifelse(.x == 1, NA, .x))) %>%
  drop_na() %>% as.data.frame()
#>   Sequence 1C_cut 2C_nocut 1C_rem 3C_cut 3C_rem 4C_nocut
#> 1       R3      1        0      0      0      0        0
#> 2       R4      0        0      0      1      0        0
#> 3       R5      1        0      0      1      0        0
```

UPDATE: Actually, it would just be better to conditionally create another variable (`drop_me`) and then use that to figure out whether a row should be dropped. This code uses the same `across(ends_with)` stuff as before, but uses it with `case_when` instead of `ifelse`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(drop_me = case_when(if_any( ( ends_with("_rem") | ends_with("_nocut") ), ~ .x == 1) ~ 1,
                             TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  filter(drop_me == 0)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 8
#>   Sequence `1C_cut` `2C_nocut` `1C_rem` `3C_cut` `3C_rem` `4C_nocut` drop_me
#>   <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 R3              1          0        0        0        0          0       0
#> 2 R4              0          0        0        1        0          0       0
#> 3 R5              1          0        0        1        0          0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  filter(!if_any(matches("_rem|_nocut"), ~.x == 1))
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  Sequence `1C_cut` `2C_nocut` `1C_rem` `3C_cut` `3C_rem` `4C_nocut`
  <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
1 R3              1          0        0        0        0          0
2 R4              0          0        0        1        0          0
3 R5              1          0        0        1        0          0
```